# Возможность размещения сервера

Tags: сервер, ip, tcp

У меня есит статический IP с длинной маски подсети /32 бита. Можно ли на таком IP разместить сервер? **(Мне провайдер предоставил IP подобного типа: ###.###.###.###/32")**

Comment: Д‌‌​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌а, можно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, чего спрашиваю, я пытаюсь сделать тестовый сервер на основе Minecraft, но при попытке подключится с не локальной сети я не могу подключиться. Хотя PORT открыт и IP пингуется. Беспонятия в чём может быть проблема.  В настройках Virtual Server введён локальный IP компьютера и нужный порт. Вот я и подумал, что у меня просто нельзя создать сервер(

Comment: Это точно внешний ip? Покажите начало

Comment: @AlexeyTen Точно, 86.57.###.###